# How do I click a tab inside a pop using vba in Internet Explorer

Tags: excel, vba

I am relatively new to VBA and I am trying to achieve this,

1. Navigate to URL
2. Click on a Button which opens a pop up that has 3 tabs
3. Click on the 3rd tab
4. Scrap some info

I have been successful with 1 and 2. But I am unable to click on any of the tabs inside the pop up using VBA.

This is the Html snippet of the pop up.

```
'<ul class="clearfix" id="historyTabs">
            <li class="ajaxCall jsonpCall selected" id="Tab1"><a href="javascript:;">Some Details</a></li>

            <li class="ajaxCall" id="Tab2"><a class="Class1" href="javascript:;">More Details</a></li>

            <li id="Tab3"><a href="javascript:;">Even more Details</a><span id="Tab31" style="display: none;"></span></li>
        </ul>
```

I tried

```
 y = 1
 Set ec = HTML.getElementsByTagName("li")
 For Each e In ec
    idvalue = e.getAttribute("id")
    If idvalue = "Tab3" Then
        idinnertext = e.innerText
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(y, 1).Value = idinnertext
        e.click
    Else 
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(y, 2).Value = "Not Tab3"
        y = y + 1
   End if
 Next e
```

The code writes "Even more details" in my excel sheet but does not click the tab.

Request some help with this.

Thanks,
Akilesh

Comment: Have you tried .FireEvent("Click")  also, why not GetElementByID("Tab3")?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav : Tried both methods Nathan. FireEvent("Click") I am getting an 'Invalid argument' error and the GetElemenetByID does not do anything.

Comment: Pop up will be having another instance of browser, hence you need to first find that new window by searching for title and then search for "Tab3" in that browser instance. It seems that your current code is  searching for Tab3 in parent instance of browser.

Comment: @J.B. But when I write the innerText after the pop up shows in Excel, it is able to get the values in the first tab(Which is 'Clicked' by default)

Comment: Hi, sorry I missed the pop up bit.  Look at using Microsoft HTML Controls properly, using the correct objects, you'll be able to decipher things like this.  Find the web browser that's opened, this is a great start  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970672.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not posting as an answer per-se, just better formatting here.  Something like this, you'll need to build around.  It uses Microsoft Internet Controls and HTML Object library.

Hope it helps

```
Sub n()

Dim arrExplorerWindows As SHDocVw.ShellWindows
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim intExplorerWindowLoop As Integer
Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim eleTab As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Set arrExplorerWindows = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows

For intExplorerWindowLoop = 0 To arrExplorerWindows.Count - 1

    If arrExplorerWindows(intExplorerWindowLoop).Name = "Internet Explorer" Then
        If arrExplorerWindows(intExplorerWindowLoop).LocationURL = _
            "http://www.investinganswers.com/" Then
            Set objIE = arrExplorerWindows(intExplorerWindowLoop)
            Set doc = objIE.Document
            Set eleTab = doc.getElementById("Tab3")
            eleTab.Click
        End If
    End If

Next intExplorerWindowLoop

End Sub
```